# Multiple Join with Linq to Entity

Tags: sql-server, linq, join, linq-to-entities, inner-join

I would like to write the following SQL queries into Linq To Entity queries.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.IdTable1 = Table1.Id
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.IdTable2 = Table2.Id

SELECT *
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.IdTable1 = Table1.Id
LEFT JOIN Table3 ON Table3.IdTable2 = Table2.Id
WHERE Table3.Id IS NULL
```

For the first one, I'm working on this :
    var query = RepoTable1.AsQueryable();
    [some query = query.Where(...)

```
query = query
  .Join(RepoTable2.AsQueryable(), e => e.IdTable1, i => i.Id, (i, e) => i)
  .GroupJoin(RepoTable3.AsQueryable(), c => c.IdTable2, eq => eq.Id, (eq, c) => eq);
```

There is something I don't understand about the Join.
Actually, "eq => eq.Id" should be of type "Table2", but it's "Table1".
If I change "(i, e) => i" to "(i, e) => e", I get an error of compilation because "query" is waiting "Table1" type.

And for the second query, I don't know how to add the "Where()" to the Join (actually, I'm mostly stuck with the first one)

Thanks in advance! Please tell me if this is not clear enough!

**Final answer :**

```
query = (from t1 in query
join t2 in RepoTable2.AsQueryable() on t1.Id equals t2.IdTable1 into joint1t2
from t2 in joint1t2.DefaultIfEmpty() // DefaultIfEmpty is used for left joins
join t3 in RepoTable3.AsQueryable() on t2.Id equals t3.IdT
select t1);
```

and for the second query :

```
query = (from t1 in query
join t2 in RepoTable2.AsQueryable() on t1.Id equals t2.IdTable1 into joint1t2
from t2 in joint1t2.DefaultIfEmpty() // DefaultIfEmpty is used for left joins
join t3 in RepoTable3.AsQueryable() on t2.Id equals t3.IdTable2 into joint2t3
from t3 in joint2t3.DefaultIfEmpty() // DefaultIfEmpty is used for left joins
where t3.Id== null
select t1);
```

Comment: I hate left joins in LINQ, but I can explain some of it for you.  `(i,e)` should likely be `(e,i)` based on your prior usage of `e` to refer to Table1, and `i` to refer to Table2.  Next up is that you shouldn't break the query up because the final return isn't (shouldn't?) be just records that are contained from table1, or you need to put the result of the second part of the query into a different variable. Thinking of it another way, `ReportTable1.AsQueryable()` returns `IQueryable<ReportTable1>`, and your final query should not be returning that.

Comment: Your final query should be returning some IQueryable of an anonymous type that includes all fields from table1, table2, and table3.

Comment: I tend to find method syntax for joins in Linq to be one of the worst things to write. Have you tried writing it in query syntax? The resulting query syntax is very similar to the SQL you already have.

Comment: Joins are fine, it's the left joins that are ugly.  I'd have much preferred if the Join just took an extra lamda for you to fill in with what you want to return if there is no match.  Something like `.Join(Inner, OuterKey, InnerKey, MatchLamda, LeftOnlyLamda, RightOnlyLamda)` used like `Table1.Join(Table2, t1=>t1.id, t2=>t2.id, (t1,t2)=>new {Name=t1.Name,Address=t2.Address}, (t1,t2)=>new {Name=t1.Name,Address=null}, (t1,t2)=>new {Name=null,Address=t2.Address})` for a full outer join.

Comment: Avoid using explicit joins in LINQ (to Entities). Always try to use navigation properties.

Comment: Thanks guys. I've used the SQL syntax. Note that I could not use the navigation properties because I have no such relation in my Database (and cannot change it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using query syntax (If you can't use navigation properties)

Your first query would look quite similar using this syntax

```
var query =
   from t1 in RepoTable1.AsQueryable()
   join t2 in RepoTable2.AsQueryable() on t1.Id equals t2.Id into t2g
   from t2 in t2g.DefaultIfEmpty() //DefaultIfEmpty is used for left joins
   join t3 in RepoTable3.AsQueryable() on t2.Id equals t3.Id
   select new 
   {
    t1, t2, t3
   };
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you. I used my variable "query" of type IQueryable<Table1> instead of RepoTable1.AsQueryable(). But now I need no "merge" my Linq-to-Entity query with the new Linq-to-SQL query. Trying to do it, but if you have any advice...